# How to subclass SubethaSmtp SMTPClient class

Tags: java, subclass, smtpclient

I am trying to develop a simple SMTPclient for testing purposes using the SubethaSmtp client package. i want to use the SMTPClient class instead of the SmartClient class for more control but i have not been able to figure out how to write mail data using SMTPClient, the only OutputStream exposed to public or external subclasses is the one for sending commands, the ones for sending data (after sending the DATA command) is exposed only to classes in the same package (SmartClient).
am i missing something here? i would like to know how a direct subclass of SMARTClient can written to work around this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are correct, you cannot simply extend the SMTPClient and get access similar to the one that SmartClient has, being a same-package class.

At this point you can either:

1) Fork your own version of the app from https://github.com/voodoodyne/subethasmtp and do whatever the hell you like with it, or

2) Go all the way and implement your own version of SMTPClient, as the package protected `SMTPClient.dotTerminatedOutput;`, used by `SmartClient.dataWrite()`  actually is just instantiated like so

```
...
this.rawOutput = this.socket.getOutputStream();                 
this.dotTerminatedOutput = new DotTerminatedOutputStream(this.rawOutput);
...
```